# How to ask for search keywords?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

There have been a number of times where I want to accomplish some goal, and I know I must not be the first person who has wanted to accomplish it.

Often, this is in situations where I am a novice or I am self-taught, and not fully familiar with the jargon or best-practices involved.  When searching online I end up stymied because my lack of vocabulary makes it hard to narrow down the search for my particular application.

I can't figure out how to ask for help in these types of situations on Stack Overflow.  For example, I once asked a question regarding whether a tool exists for distributing self-signed certificate keys to the end-user, which was closed as subjective.

Originally I tried phrasing it in an objective manner (*i.e.* "Does [tool] exist, and if so what should I be searching for?"), but that didn't fly.

Is there a proper way to ask Stack Overflow for a starting point?

Comment: Use the stackoverflow chat.

Comment: @epascarello but that privilege is unlocked at 20 rep....

Comment: Then earn 20 rep first?

Comment: Pretty easy to get 20 rep. Start up voting.

Comment: @epascarello up voting takes 15 rep, not really that much better...

Comment: Start asking more questions... :)

Comment: Start answering *good* questions.

Comment: Both question and answers here focus on searching for tools. A somewhat different scenario is when one needs keywords for a concept. I believe that entirely reasonable questions may arise out of that, even though some of them would fit better in Programmers or Theoretical CS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want know if a program or API exists, you could look at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). That link goes directly to their question guidelines page. They have a very specific set of criteria for posting questions there so that their questions can be objective enough to have specific answers. (Just asking if something exists is not going to be good enough.)

I also recommend looking at [recent questions with high scores](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aquestion%20score%3a5...%20created%3a1y%20closed%3ano) to see good examples of what your question should look like.

Comment: So the solution is "go to the SE that allows subjective questions"?  I guess that could work...

Comment: Well, Bill's #2 is a really good option too. People can answer with, "There's a tool for this", you just can ask for only those types of answers.

Answer (score 32):

Asking for tool recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but you still have a couple of options.

1. If you know you're looking for a tool to perform a particular task, you can ask about it in a related chat room (once you have the required 20 reputation to enter chat rooms).
2. If you're not even sure if a tool exists, or what you're looking for, you need to make your question more general. Instead of asking for a tool or other off-site resource, just ask *how to do* the thing you're trying to do. You'll likely get a variety of answers, and if a tool already exists someone will probably mention it.

In addition to #2, chat is also an option if you're really stuck on what keywords to search for.

Comment: A note should be added that pay attention to the recommended similar questions when you're typing your question. Though being marked duplicate could help you find your solution it won't help you move forward on the site. So it is normally better to find your solution before being marked duplicate. :D

Comment: Super helpful Bill - I think a lot of new members would benefit from this methodology.

Comment: The problem with #2, is that it's broadening the question makes it deviate very much from what I'm actually seeking.  I don't want to learn how to re-invent the wheel from scratch, I want to be pointed in the right direction so I can find the book about wheels in the library, and searching for "round thing that spins" isn't helping.

Comment: @Frank If you ask how to make a round thing that spins, someone will inevitably tell you to use an already existing wheel. Someone else might tell you how to make one. Having both answers available is better for everyone.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Is it better for everyone?  There's an inherent difference between the user who wants to write their own tool and the user who can't even synthesize a proper search phrase for it.  As I imagine it, a future visitor is only going to be looking for one answer or the other, and the rest of the answers will be noise.  I think BSMP was on the right track--the two "answers" are getting at entirely different topics, and it sounds like I need to be more careful which exchange I post my question to so I can keep it on-topic.